# KineticJS - set portion of group/image dragable

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

This is what I need in KineticJS:

I have a large 300x300 image, I want to be able to drag it, but only if I click-drag in the upper quarter of the image.  if I try to drag the rest of this image, I don't want it to move.  Is this possible?

Furthermore, If I try to drag this image, how can I make it drag the rest of the items in the group along with it?

Comment: Add draggable and the `'dragstart'` event to the group, check the mouse x/y when they start dragging and return false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/NnD5q/

```
box.on('mousedown', function(e){
    var bX = box.attrs.x, bY = box.attrs.y;

    // set draggable false if they aren't in our click range 
    // (a 20x20 square in the top left)
    if (e.x > bX + 20 || e.y > bY + 20)
        box.setDraggable(false);          
});
window.onmouseup = function(e){
    box.setDraggable(true);  // set draggable true on **window** mouseup.
};
```

Another option would be to create a drag handle object, `group.setDraggable(true)` on mousedown for that drag handle, then `group.setDraggable(false)` on window mouseup. This second option is likely much cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

the easiest thing to do would be to create a custom hit region function that defines a rectangular region in the top right corner of the image.  Here's an example:

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-custom-hit-function-tutorial/